# Показать перестановку строк в диффе

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, jetbrains, diff

Можно ли как-то показывать дифф так, чтобы строки кода, только поменявшиеся местами, но не изменившиеся показывались по-особому? Сейчас это показывается как добавление+удаление в одном diff окне и удаление+добавление в другом. Если нельзя, то может есть другой продвинутый diff tool, а не дефолтный, который это может?

Comment: Типа [такого](http://www.semanticmerge.com/features/)?

Comment: @GrAnd да, спасибо; попробую заинтегрировать